# About changing the text naviagting through the Dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery. I need to navigate through the DOM to change the text of Change Me to best when button btnChangeText is clicked.

```
//HTML
<div>
  <p>
    <span>Some Text</span>% <span id="spnTwo">More Text</span>%<span>Thie Text</span>
  </p>
  <p><span>Max Text</span>= <span>Change Me</span>=<spna>Less Text</spna></p>
</div>
<button id="btnChangeText">Change the Span</button>

//jQuery
$("#btnChangeText").click(function () {
    $('.spnTwo').children('span').text("Best");
});
```

Can you please help to figure out my mistakes. What should i do next to get the text changed.

Comment: What error are you running into ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your jquery. You've used . instead of #. When using ID you should use # to target it. Your code is very messy. Make sure your code is clear.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#btnChangeText").click(function () {
        $('#spnTwo').text("Best");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
         <p>
            <span> Some Text</span>% <span>More Text</span>
            %<span>Thie Text</span></p>
            <p><span>Max Text</span>= <span id="spnTwo">Change Me</span>
            = <spna>Less Text</spna></p>

        </div>
        <button id="btnChangeText">Change the Span</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But i need to change the text of Change me to Best, Is there specific way to do it.

Comment: @SushilPathak Updated. Just move the id.

Comment: @SushilPathak Please check the answer again and tick if it answered your question.

Comment: One more thing, make sure you have a link to the jQuery library to make your jQuery code work.
Add this link to your HTML and make sure it it before your script code not after: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: It doesn't work. I already added that jquery link from the google. But it is not working.